# RecycleView highlights the wrong row (Android)

Tags: android

I am trying to highlight implement a list such as when the user clicks on a row its background changes color. The app works fine but when I scroll up and down the list, while one row is highlighted, suddenly other rows get highlighted too.
The following is a test app that shows this behavior (code is based on http://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-set-recycleview-item-row-background-color-in-android/).

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<ItemObject> posts = returnListItems();

    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private List<ItemObject> returnListItems(){
    List<ItemObject> items = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    items.add(new ItemObject("Blank Space", "Taylor Swift", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Uptown Funk", "Mark Ronson", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Can't Feel My Face", "The Weeknd", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Cheerleader", "OMI", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("What Do You Mean?", "Justin Bieber", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Hello", "Adele", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Blank Space", "Taylor Swift", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Uptown Funk", "Mark Ronson", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Can't Feel My Face", "The Weeknd", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Cheerleader", "OMI", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("What Do You Mean?", "Justin Bieber", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Hello", "Adele", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Blank Space", "Taylor Swift", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Uptown Funk", "Mark Ronson", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Can't Feel My Face", "The Weeknd", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Cheerleader", "OMI", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("What Do You Mean?", "Justin Bieber", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Hello", "Adele", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Blank Space", "Taylor Swift", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Uptown Funk", "Mark Ronson", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Can't Feel My Face", "The Weeknd", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Cheerleader", "OMI", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("What Do You Mean?", "Justin Bieber", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Hello", "Adele", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Blank Space", "Taylor Swift", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Uptown Funk", "Mark Ronson", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Can't Feel My Face", "The Weeknd", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Cheerleader", "OMI", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("What Do You Mean?", "Justin Bieber", "2016"));
    items.add(new ItemObject("Hello", "Adele", "2016"));
    return items;
}
```

**RecyclerViewHolders**

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

public TextView songTitle;
public TextView songYear;
public TextView songAuthor;

private static int selectedPos = -1;
private static View selectedView = null;

public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    songTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    songYear = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_year);
    songAuthor = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_author);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    if (selectedPos == position){       // deselect the row
        selectedView.setSelected(false);
        selectedPos = -1;   // no selected row
    }else {
        if (selectedPos != -1)
            selectedView.setSelected(false);           // deselect the row
        selectedView = view;
        selectedPos = position;
        selectedView.setSelected(true);
    }
}
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders>{

private List<ItemObject> itemList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    return new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.songTitle.setText("" + position + "   Song Title: " + itemList.get(position).getSongTitle());
    holder.songYear.setText("Song Year: " + itemList.get(position).getSongYear());
    holder.songAuthor.setText("Song Author: " + itemList.get(position).getSongAuthor());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.itemList.size();
}
}
```

**ItemObject**

```
public class ItemObject {

private String songTitle;
private String songYear;
private String songAuthor;

public ItemObject(String songTitle, String songYear, String songAuthor) {
    this.songTitle = songTitle;
    this.songYear = songYear;
    this.songAuthor = songAuthor;
}

public String getSongTitle() {
    return songTitle;
}

public String getSongYear() {
    return songYear;
}

public String getSongAuthor() {
    return songAuthor;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you posted the full code of `RecyclerViewHolders`? I don't see how `selectedView` is initialized.

Comment: It is initialized in onClick() once a row is selected (initially it is set to null) - see the line 'selectedView = view'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in Recycler View the view gets recycled. That means same view is used again for displaying other items. So once the other view starts using the same view which has been selected it starts showing incorrect results.

To correct this you will have to make modifications in your onBindViewHolder code. Something like below :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
       View view = holder.getView(); //Please check the appropriate function which returns the "itemView" from view holder.
       if(position == holder.getSelectedPosition()) //Add a getter method for selected position
       {
          view.setSelected(true);
       }
       else {
          view.setSelected(false);
        }

        holder.songTitle.setText("" + position + "   Song Title: " + itemList.get(position).getSongTitle());
        holder.songYear.setText("Song Year: " + itemList.get(position).getSongYear());
        holder.songAuthor.setText("Song Author: " + itemList.get(position).getSongAuthor());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Aprit Ratan. It worked. The missing "function" is View view = holder.itemView;

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)